# How can I extract many P7M (pkcs#7) signed files?

Tags: batch, digital-signature, pkcs

I have many P7M files and I need to extract them to unsigned original file, I found some free tools but with these I have to extract each one and I want something to do a massive extraction or a command line to use in a batch command.
Can I find something for this?

Answer (score 3):

I got the answer using openssl:

```
openssl.exe smime -verify -in file.P7M -noverify -inform DEM -out test.txt
```